# Using Sharepoint 2013 Search.asmx with FQL

Tags: 2013, search, sharepoint-search, kql

I have a website using sharepoint search services to query SP index. After migrating to 2013 I started getting this error:

ERROR_BAD_QUERY

Error: We didn't understand your search terms. Make sure they're using proper syntax.

Here is my Query XML:

```
<QueryPacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Query">
  <Query>
    <Context>
      <QueryText language="en" type="FQL"><![CDATA[string("TEST", mode="and") AND filter(contentsource:equals("MyContnentSource"))]]></QueryText>
    </Context>
    <SupportedFormats Format="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document" />
    <ResultProvider>FASTSearch</ResultProvider>
    <Range>
      <StartAt>1</StartAt>
      <Count>10</Count>
    </Range>
    <TrimDuplicates>false</TrimDuplicates>
    <Properties>
      <Property name="Rank" />
      <Property name="Title" />
      <Property name="Size" />
      <Property name="Path" />
      <Property name="Description" />
      <Property name="Teaser" />
      <Property name="Write" />
    </Properties>
  </Query>
</QueryPacket>
```

I tried to run the query with type="KQL". It does not complain about anything also does not bring back anything...

what is the fastest way to fix this problem? I would rather not try to change the Query Type...

Comment: Your query does not look that complex. When you moved to 2013 did you also migrate your managed properties and content sources? What happens when you run the analogous KQL query in a search center? "test ContentSource=MyContentSource" If it fails in the search center it won't work in your code.

Comment: There are no managed properties to be migrated. This content source is for a non-sharepoint site. could you please tell me how to run an analogous KQL query in search center?

Comment: I did. It's in my comment. "test ContentSource=MyContentSource"